# Writing a function for taking two argument with potential key and a dictionary name

Tags: python

I have been working on this question, I have tried a couple different codes like

```
test_dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

def show_value():
    i = ()
    if i in test_dictionary:
        pass
else:
    print((i)('is not a valid key'))
```

*and*

```
test_dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

def show_value(i, test_dictionary):
    if i in test_dictionary:
        pass
    else:
        print(i, 'is not a valid key')
```

I have to write a function using `show_value()` that takes two arguments

- a potential key and
- a dictionary name.

If the potential key is in the dictionary, the function should return the value for that key. If the potential key, say invalid_key, is not in the dictionary, it should return the string:

invalid_key is not a valid key.

what is it I am doing wrong? I cannot figure this out?

Comment: You're not returning anything when the key is in the dictionary, you're just doing `pass`. And when it's not in the dictionary, you're printing a message, not returning a string.

Comment: `print(test_dictionary.get(i, f"{i} is not a valid key"))`  - dict.get(..) already provides your functionality: `def show_value(key,d): return d.get(key, f"{key} is not a valid key"))`

Comment: The first version also doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries have a built-in method `.get()` that returns a value from a dictionary, or a default value if it isn't. You can use that.

```
def show_value(i, test_dictionary):
    return test_dictionary.get(i, f"{i} is not a valid key")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the below. If i is found then return the value using test_dictionary[i] else return a string saying "not found". `

```
test_dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

def show_value(i, test_dictionary):
    if i in test_dictionary:
        return(test_dictionary[i])
    else:
        return(str(i) + ' is not a valid key')
        
print(show_value(3,test_dictionary))
```

`

Answer (score -1):

```
def show_value(i, test_dictionary):
    if i in test_dictionary.keys():
        return test_dictionnary[i]   #rerurn the value associated with the key
    else: 
        return(str(i)+' is not a valid key')
```

Is this what you are looking to achieve ?

Comment: You don't need `.keys()`

Comment: And the instructions say to return the error message, not print it.